# Tomcat crashes because of native C code - Possible workarounds?

Tags: java, tomcat, crash, native, rmi

We have a web application hosted on tomcat and it contains calls to some of the legacy C code. Now, on in one of the scenario this C code crashed in production environment and caused the entire JVM to crash bringing the app server down for almost 15 minutes.

Question - Is there a better way to this, basically I want to load the native code in its own JVM so that the app server does not crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up by doing the following:

1. Moved and exposed the C specific code to a URL endpoint, i.e. RPC style web service (basically a remote call):

@WebService   @SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)

And subsequently exposing its interface endpoint:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface..
```

2. During web server init published this endpoint `Endpoint.publish(...)` in a new java process using `ProcessBuilder`.
3. When using this, called the endpoint and got the object itself using `javax.xml.ws.Service`.
4. During server stop we destroyed the `Process` created in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question. Move it to another JVM and then make service calls to that JVM. If the server crashes, communications to the JVM will be lost, but your app server will still be running and can handle the failed communications gracefully.

Your options are, put the code in another app server and create a service API using JSON, Web Services etc, whatever you are more comfortable with.  Or, depending on what the C code is doing, maybe just a socket level API.

Of course your C code could handle it's own sockets if you were up to writing that. But keeping it in an App server is probably best for management and monitoring reasons. And it would be quicker and more flexible in creating the API.

You would have to use your judgement as to which is the best solution for you.